# How to return string attached to largest integer in an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, object

So I have a function that takes in an array of objects with the parameters of (name, traffic) where name is a String and traffic is an int. e.g [{"Monday",12},{"Tuesday",10}] The function then is supposed to return the name/names which have the highest traffic value

However I can't figure out how to return either just the name associated to the object e.g "Monday", or how to return multiply names in an array for objects that share the highest traffic. e.g ["Monday", "Tuesday"]

Here's my code so far;

```
function mostPopularDays(week) {
 if (week == null || week == []){
  return null;
 }
 /*just so it returns null if nothing is given*/
 var arr = [];
 var largest = week[0];
 for (var i = 0; i<week.length; i++){
   if (largest < week[i]){
    largest = week[i]
      }
    }
 arr.push(largest);
 /*takes the largest value and puts it in an array*/
 for (var i = 0; i<week.length; i++){
   if (week[i.] == largest){
    arr.push(week[i]);
     }
   }
 /*takes values that have the same amount and adds them to the array*/
 if(arr.length = 1){
 return arr[0]
   }
 /*returns the object if the array has just one entry*/
 return arr;
 }
```

Comment: `{"Monday",12}` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `if(arr.length = 1)` is _not_ a comparison. `week == []` will _never_ work as you expect (see comment below). `week[i.]` is invalid.

Comment: @Xufox even worse, it will be, e.g. when `week === 0`

Comment: @ASDFGerte I know, it's just to demonstrate that I'm inputting objects into the array

Comment: @Xufox that comment is talking about what is going on above it not below

Comment: The issue is you should tell us the format of said objects, otherwise it is hard to help. Therefore, using invalid syntax to describe them is not a good idea.

Comment: @ASDFGerte right, but didn't I mention that the objects are of the form (name, traffic) where name is the string and traffic is the int? Or is that not the format?

Comment: is that `{ name: "Monday", traffic: 12 }` or `{ Monday: 12 }` or ... ?

Comment: @ASDFGerte its {name: "Monday", traffic: 12}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass objects as key value pair inside array.

```js
function mostPopularDays(week) {
 if (week == null || week == []){
  return null;
 }
 /*just so it returns null if nothing is given*/
 var arr = [];
 var largest = week[0].traffic;
 for (var i = 0; i<week.length; i++){
   if (largest < week[i].traffic){
    largest = week[i].traffic
      }
 }

 /*takes the largest value and puts it in an array*/
 for (var i = 0; i<week.length; i++){
   if (week[i].traffic == largest){
    arr.push(week[i].name);
    }
 }
 
if(arr.length==1)
{
  arr = arr[0];
}
 
return arr; 
}

var obj1 = [{name:"Monday",traffic:10},{name:"Sunday",traffic:20},{name:"Wednesday",traffic:22}];

//will return string 
console.log(mostPopularDays(obj1));

var obj2 = [{name:"Monday",traffic:10},{name:"Sunday",traffic:20},{name:"Wednesday",traffic:20}];

//will return array
console.log(mostPopularDays(obj2));
```

Comment: Thanks, there's just one issue. I was hoping to obtain a String not an Array if there was only one object with the highest traffic but when I create an if statement to deal with this it fails to return an array for when two or more objects have the highest traffic. Is this just inevitable?

Comment: @Anton Let me make a change for it and it will work.

Comment: @Anton Just added what you needed

Answer (score 0):

Based on you question(Assuming your traffic values are positive integers.), here is the code:

```js
function mostPopularDays(week) {
          if (week == null || week == []){
            return null;
          }
          /*just so it returns null if nothing is given*/
          //based on what you explained 'week' looks like [{'name': 'Monday', 'traffic': 10},.....]
          var arr = [];
          var max = 0;
          //checking for the maximum traffic value available in the week array
          for (var i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
            if(week[i].traffic > max) {
              max = week[i].traffic;
            }
          }
          // push all the objects with max traffic value
          for (var i = 0; i<week.length; i++) {
            if (week[i].traffic === max){
              arr.push(week[i].name);
            }
          }
          if(arr.length > 1) {
            return arr;
          } else if(arr.length === 1) {
            return arr[0].name;
          }
        }
        var x = [{'name': 'Monday', 'traffic': 10}, {'name': 'Sunday', 'traffic': 20}, {'name': 'Tuesday', 'traffic': 12}, {'name': 'Friday', 'traffic': 20},{'name': 'Thursday', 'traffic': 15}];
        console.log(mostPopularDays(x));
```

However, as ASDFGerte & Xufox mentioned, a standard JS object will have key-value pairs. You can check it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp).

Comment: Does not work as intended. Biggest problem: `if (week[i] === max){`. Also as commented on the question already, `week == []` is not a good idea at all

Comment: Still will not work as intended, you are pushing object itself in arr - `arr.push(week[i])`

Comment: @dhaker, I wasn't clear of what he wanted as the output, so please check the comment next to it.

Comment: my output should be the day e.g "Monday" or if there are multiple days with the highest traffic then those days but in an array. e.g ["Monday","Tuesday"]
Your code works but I tried with two objects that had the same highest traffic and only the first object's name was returned in the array

Answer (score 0):

A shorter one-line ES6 alternative:

```
var arr = [{name:"Monday",traffic:10},{name:"Sunday",traffic:20},{name:"Wednesday",traffic:20}];

var result = arr.sort((a,b) => b.traffic - a.traffic).filter(({traffic}, i, arr) => traffic === arr[0].traffic).map(({name}) => name);

console.log(result);
```